# Does multiplying a wildcard in viper mean anything?

Tags: viper-lang

A bug in VerCors generated some silver that looks like:

```
field f: Int

method test(n: Int, x: Ref)
requires n == 100
requires acc(x.f, wildcard * n)    
{}
```

Viper seems to accept this, but I don't understand what it would mean, if anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, it means that the callee obtains a tiny (but non-zero) permission amount — times n. In effect, this should be no different from just obtaining the tiny amount (i.e. `acc(x.f, wildcard)`), although one can maybe engineer contrived situations, in probably involving `perm`, in which it makes a difference.

Bottom line: The example is indeed somewhat confusing and the semantics not totally obvious, but everything is well defined.